# Are there more solutions to $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$ than all $x_i$ equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Are there more solutions to
$$x_nx_1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_ix_{i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$$
than just $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

In the case $n=2$ the answer is NO, since
$$x_1x_2+x_2x_1=x_1^2+x_2^2\;\Leftrightarrow\; x_1^2-2x_1x_2+x_2^2=0\;\Leftrightarrow\; (x_1-x_2)^2=0\;\Leftrightarrow\; x_1=x_2.$$
Already in case $n=3$, i.e. $\;x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\;$ it's not that easy.

What are the answeres for $n\geq 3$? My guess: NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca, \forall a,b,c \in \Bbb R^+$. Hope you know when equality holds in AM-GM or Rearrangement Inequality.

Otherwise you can go for this,

$2a^2+2b^2+2c^2=2ab+2bc+2ca$

$\implies (a^2-2ab+b^2)+(b^2-2bc+c^2)+(c^2-2ca+a^2)=0$

$\implies (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0$

Since, LHS is always non-negative($a,b,c \in \Bbb R$) [Why?], we get

$a-b=b-c=c-a=0$

$\implies a=b=c$ or as you would like it $x_1=x_2=x_3.$

Answer (score 0):

If numbers may be complex, answer for 3 is YES

Let x1x2 + x2x3 + x3x1 = 3

(x1 + x2 + x3)^2 = x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + 2*(x1x2 + x2x3 + x3x1) = 9

let x1,x2,x3 are roots     of x^3 - 3*x^2 + 3x - 100 = 0